# How can I determine how many instances (DaemonChildren) of Sendmail were created at a specific historical point in time?

Tags: centos, sendmail

CentOS 5 / Sendmail 8.14

I'm researching an intermittent issue that may be caused by too many instances (DaemonChildren) of Sendmail getting created.  Is this information documented in the logs somewhere?

If there isn't a way to retrieve this information from the logs, what's the easiest way to monitor this (over a period of time)?

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail may log it during queue runs (LogLevel>8) `Skipping queue run -- too many children`

You may use `smcontrol.pl` in contrib to poll sendmail daemon status info over control socket (ControlSocketName). `status` and `mstat` (machine readable format) report also number of children.

Comment: Hmm... strange.  I don't see smcontrol.pl on my server (searched it all).  Is it an optional tool?  Would similar output be in `ps`?

Comment: On Debian smcontrol.pl is located at `/usr/share/sendmail/smcontrol.pl` and provided by `sendmail-base` package.  It is a simple script (with a lot of comments) - IMHO you may get what you need using netcat and grep.

Comment: Good idea! I assume you mean `netstat` instead of `netcat` right?

Comment: No.  Anyway I have wrongly assumed netcat supports connections over unix sockets (entries in unix filesystem).  If you want to treat smcontrol.pl as sample/reference implementation then its source is available e.g. at https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/sendmail/sendmail-26.2/sendmail/contrib/smcontrol.pl